# Can't find ForecastingItem sObject in DescribeGlobalResult

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, sobject, describesobject

We recently upgraded to salesforce API v27 (from 21). Documentation says that there are some new objects added between v21 and v27. ForecastingItem object is one such object. But when I get all the sObjects from DescribeGlobalResult, it doesn't list ForecastingItem, ForecastingQuota etc.

I am under the impression that new objects(tables) are added automatically by salesforce(they don't contain any data, data is added by the consumer of those tables) and getting the metadata from DescribeGlobalResult should return all objects.

Please correct me if I'm wrong? Do we need to add these objects on the source or they are added automatically? If they are added automatically, then I should be able to see those through DescribeGlobalResult. Also If I'm suppose to add those objects, would they not be customized objects instead of default salesforce objects?

More Info:

I'm not sure about if it's customizable forecasting, I am new to salesforce.

I am missing not only these objects but also columns from some tables. For ex: Account is missing the following columns added in v24:

v24 changes in Account table:

The Account object now includes these fields.

DataDotComCleanStatus: Indicates the record's clean status as compared with Data.com. Values are: Not 
Compared, In Sync, Reviewed, Different, Not Found, or Inactive.

DunsNumber: The Data Universal Numbering System (D-U-N-S) number is a unique, nine-digit number 
assigned to every business location in the Dun & Bradstreet database that has a unique, separate, and distinct 
operation. D-U-N-S numbers are used by industries and organizations around the world as a global standard for 
business identification and tracking. Maximum size is 9 characters.

NaicsCode: The six-digit North American Industry Classification System (NAICS) code is the standard used 
by business and government to classify business establishments into industries, according to their economic activity 
for the purpose of collecting, analyzing, and publishing statistical data related to the U.S. business economy. 
Maximum size is 8 characters.

NaicsDesc: A brief description of an organization's line of business, based on its NAICS code. Maximum size 
is 120 characters.

Tradestyle: A name, different from its legal name, that an organization may use for conducting business. 
Similar to "Doing business as" or "DBA". Maximum length is 255 characters.

YearStarted: The date when an organization was legally established. Maximum length is 4 characters. 
The Lead object now includes these fields.

vCompanyDunsNumber: The Data Universal Numbering System (D-U-N-S) number is a unique, nine-digit 
number assigned to every business location in the Dun&Bradstreet database that has a unique, separate, and 
distinct operation. D-U-N-S numbers are used by industries and organizations around the world as a global 
standard for business identification and tracking. Maximum size is 9 characters. "

Thanks
Gill

Comment: Is it dependent on Customizable Forecasting being enabled? Some object are feature dependent and only available when you've enabled the relevant feature.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added more information above in response to your comment. It won't let me add all of that here.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you try installing Ajax Tools into your org. Its free on the App Exchange. Once installed, all you need do is click on any Object from the Explorer portion of Ajax Tools, then select the schema describe button below the query builder box. A query will be returned with all results on that object in a nicely formatted table (just expand the results).

Its could be possible you may have missed something in your previous query. The tool also has very useful parent child schema links which you can easily traverse to find look-ups. It might help you find any of the missing objects you're looking for. Either that or it will provide the verification that for some reason, they're not in your org. The results can normally be selected for a copy/paste into an excel spreadsheet which you could easily forward to whomever you needed to.